# How to get a specific substring from a column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Orders table that has one of the columns called "details" as:

```
Contact ID: A18YTX7GWEJRU8    City/Site and Site Name: Orlando - Orlando (UFL4)    Date of Call (MM/DD/YYYY): 01/23/2017    Time of Call (Local Time): 16:44    Order ID(s): 112-0654231-9637802    Call Summary: Cx did not receive. Order marked as delivered to doorstep at 16:27      created by flx-cstech on behalf of sssmiley.
```

There are different cell values in that column. Also could be like:

```
Short Description: Dry Ice Retrieval    Please enter the following information for the site ops to pick up the dry ice from the customer:    Contact ID:AD3R60PA1QCCF    Order ID:112-6254812-3186644
```

Or anything else.

I just want to extract the `Order ID(s): 112-0654231-9637802` part from it. How do I do that?

Comment: should be able to use REGEXP_LIKE

Comment: Any example please? All the examples I'm seeing use regexp_like in the where clause, but I just want to save order_id as another column

Comment: use regexp_like and set the as your substr(starting location) and get the  regexp_like  "Call Summary" and make this point as the end location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_column,
         'Order\s+ID(\s*\(s\))?:\s*\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}'
       )
FROM   your_table
```

To just get the number you can wrap the number in a capture group:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_column,
         'Order\s+ID(\s*\(s\))?:\s*(\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7})',
         1,                                              -- Start from the 1st character
         1,                                              -- Get the 1st match
         NULL,                                           -- Apply default flags
         2                                               -- Get the 2nd capture group
       )
FROM   your_table
```

Or, if you do not have anything else with the same 3-digit, dash, 7-digit, dash, 7-digit format:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         your_column,
         '\d{3}-\d{7}-\d{7}',
       )
FROM   your_table
```

Comment: Can I just get the number from the order id i.e., 112-0654231-9637802?

Answer (score 0):

Your string looks like a fixed format string, so the simplest way would be:

```
select substr(detail, 160, 31)
```

Comment: what if the site name is longer than "Orlando" like mississippi?

Comment: Could you please explain what it this 160,31? The Order ID comes at different locations in each field of that column.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn . . . Then presumably it would not be followed by as many spaces.  The field looks like  a fixed-format field, lacking any other information.

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_re.htm

> REGEXP_LIKE This function searches a character column for a pattern. Use this
>   function in the WHERE clause of a query to return rows matching the
>   regular expression you specify.

and similar functions

Comment: I think you're talking about regexp_substr . But I don't know regex. Answer for this would be appreciated

Comment: if i can only get sql fiddle to work but not at this stage.